# How to prevent Bevel and Emboss effect from creating border around tile in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to create a vertically and horizontally repeatable stained glass image using Photoshop CS5 and I have applied Drop Shadow, Bevel and Emboss, and Pattern Overlay effects to the one layer that I am using.  After saving the image, I noticed that when I tile the image there is a single pixel border on the right and bottom of the image and through process of elimination I have observed that it is the Bevel and Emboss effect that is causing this border to appear.

I've tried adjusting the settings for Bevel and Emboss without much luck so I'm wondering if I have to resort to some kind of trick such as increasing the size of the image, applying the effect, and then cropping out the border.  I'm not very experienced with Photoshop though so my question is what is the easiest way to get rid of that border and retain the repeatability of the image?

Here are the settings I have chosen for Bevel and Emboss:

- Style: Inner Bevel
- Technique: Smooth
- Depth: 71%
- Direction: Up
- Size: 1px
- Soften: 0px
- Angle: 120
- Use Global Light: No
- Altitude: 65
- Gloss Contour: Default (45deg straight line from lower left to upper right with darkened lower right)
- Anti-aliased: No
- Highlight Mode: Screen (Color: #ffffff, Opacity: 75%)
- Shadow Mode: Multiply (Color: #000000, Opacity: 75%)

Here's what the image currently looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way:

Make the tiling area larger than needed, apply your effects, export, then crop to the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I just came across this and found a solution so I figured I would post it for anyone who still needs it.

Right click on the layer with the bevel, select "create layers" and then you will have two different layers that compose the bevel effect. You can now take the eraser tool and erase the border around the edge of the image.